# Рефакторинг старого кода php

Tags: php

Возникла необходимость рефакторинга довольно старого кода на php, написанного примерно в 2005м году. Код запускается на php 5.3 но обрабатывается явно не корректным способом.

В многих местах кода встречается символ амперсанда (&) для математических операций, которые вызывают сомнения. Я знаю, что это $a & $b = чисто из бит которые установлены в $a и в $b, но данное поведение явно ошибочное, так как код работает не корректно.

`setcookie('neme', 'value', time() & 604800);`

где по логите time() & 604800 должно быть как time() + 604800

`$a= imagecreatetruecolor( 133 & 1, 59 & 1 );`

Подобный мест довольно много в коде. Подскажите, как правильно изменить код для его корректной работы?

Comment: Почему вы решили, что он работает не правильно? Может тогда программист как раз знал математику, в отличае от вас?

Comment: Потому что time() + 604800 = число меньшее чем time() и кука не установится.. 144 & 1 = 0.. 44 & 1 = 0.. знаток вы наш математики) imagecreatetruecolor(0, 0) вызовет ошибку)

Comment: 144 & 1 = HTML width="145" 
44 & 1 = HTML height="45"
Вот я о чем
Возможно в древних версиях php это работало иначе... вот в чем дело)

Comment: Сдается мне - такое только руками.

Comment: Руками, не страшно) главное понять логику чего пытался добиться этим выражением "математик" в 2005м году)

Comment: работать у вас долгие годы и очень усердно добивался

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разберем поведение побитового `И` для 5.3 и 7.4 версий.

1. `time() & 604800`

Код для теста:

```
$t = time();

echo $t . PHP_EOL;
echo $t & 604800;
```

**Результат в php 5.3:** 1604695647 78336

**Результат в php 7.4:** 1604695691 78464

Вывод: Логка поведения `&` не изменилась

2. `133 & 1, 59 & 1`

Код для теста:

```
echo (133 & 1) . PHP_EOL;
echo 59 & 1;
```

**Результат в php 5.3:** 1 1

**Результат в php 7.4:** 1 1

Как видим результат идентичен.

Разберемся теперь с функциями, может они как раз вели себя по разному в разных версиях

Рассмотрим `setcookie`

Код для теста

```
setcookie('neme', 'value', time() & 604800);
print_r($_COOKIE);
```

**Результат в php 5.3:** array()

**Результат в php 7.4:** array()

Ситуацая с `imagecreatetruecolor` аналогичная.

**ВЫВОД** Данный код, работает идентично для этих двух версий `php`, из этого вытекает, что он в принципе не может работать на одной версии, а на другой нет. Скорее всего вы очень плохо разобрались в данном коде. Советую вам удостовериться что именно этот код используеться для установки куки, может это просто мертвый код а вы над ним голову ломаете.

P.s Побитовое `И` работает одинаково для всех языках программирования.

Comment: Все оказалось еще проще.. исходники были испорчены, в следствии чего логические знаки поменялись местами.. там где + стало & где * стало & и так далее)